# Can't run Ubuntu installed on a USB drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

After having trouble with my Ubuntu installation on a USB drive (I found out that I had to create EFI System Partition), I can't launch Ubuntu. I read that Safe Boot Mode might be the issue, but it is turned off. The second USB drive broke down while trying to install Ubuntu on it, so I can't try out a different device.

Here's what it looks like.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwmNl.jpg]

Comment: Are you sure that your second USB drive broke down? Maybe there is 'only confusion' due to some written data, and it might be possible to restore it to a standard storage device. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035).

Comment: What system do you want on your USB drive? 1. A **live-only** or 2. a **persistent live** or 3. an **installed** system (installed like into an internal drive)? The advice will depend on what kind of system you want.

Comment: I want an installed system

Comment: I suggest that you try according to the following link: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312). It helps if you can unplug, disconnect or via software settings disable the internal drive (particularly if you want to install in UEFI mode).

Comment: @majster_klepka Could you please check the contents of */etc/fstab* on USB flash - for what partition this UUID is used? Please add this info to the question. Also add output of `sudo lsblk -f` with inserted USB flash y

Comment: @N0rbert /etc/fstab was empty and I didn't get any output of the command you suggested.

However, I installed Ubuntu according to the link from sudodus and it works! Thank you. 

I have another question: Can I manage remaining space and create a partition to be used as a regular flash storage? After installation I have 49 GB of free space. I am going to use Ubuntu to learn web development so leaving 19 GB for it and 30 GB for storage would be great.

Comment: @majster_klepka for compatibility with MS Windows ordinary data storage partition should be the first partition. This will prevent accidental formating of it in Windows. But you having data partition is a good idea, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I should have mentioned at the beginning that I want to have a second partition for storage. 
I used the LiveCD to unmount the USB drive with Ubuntu installed on it (with the method from sudodus) and allocate some space for storage. However, after creating second partition I could no longer run Ubuntu.
I tried installing it once again, this time making the storage partition the first one. I chose FAT32 and set mount point to /windows. Then I allocated remaining space for Ubuntu, chose ext4 file system, set the mount point to /, and chose the USB drive (not Ubuntu partition) as the device for bootloader instalation. However, it still doesn't work.
Here's the error message I get when trying to run it. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL0RA.jpg